# Including subprojects using a wildcard in a Gradle settings file

Tags: java, groovy, build, gradle

In Gradle you need to define subprojects to be built in a 'settings.gradle' file. To build three child projects, you would do something like this:

```
include "child1", "child2", "child3"
```

The problem I'm having is that I have quite a few projects to include. Is there a way to use a wildcard in this definition? I'm looking for something like this:

```
include "*"
```

That of course does not work. This would be a lot easier to work with since I have many subprojects to include. Is there a way to automatically include subdirectories as projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like:

```
include (1..10).collect { "Child$it" }
```

To include "Child1" up to "Child10"?

Obviously, you'd need to change the collect to some sort of folder scan, but it that quick test works then the scan has a good chance

Comment: "child1" and "child2" were just for the example. The real names of the projects do not have numbers in them. I was hoping there was a built in feature for this without resorting to listing the files in the directory, but I guess maybe there is not.

Comment: Does

include new File( '.' ).listFiles().findAll { it.isDirectory() } .collect { it.name }

work?

Answer (score 6):

```
include rootDir.listFiles().findAll { 
     it.isDirectory() 
     && !( it =~ ".*/\\..*") // don't add directories starting with '.'
     && !( it =~ "^\\..*") // don't add directories starting with '.'
    }.collect { 
        it.getName() 
    }.toArray(new java.lang.String[0])
```

Did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

The following code supports a project hierarchy of arbitrary depth:

```
rootDir.eachFileRecurse { f ->
    if ( f.name == "build.gradle" ) {
        String relativePath = f.parentFile.absolutePath - rootDir.absolutePath
        String projectName = relativePath.replaceAll("[\\\\\\/]", ":")
        include projectName
    }
}
```